# redis reconnect to db0 after connection error

Tags: python, redis, reconnect

I run several programs on the same redis server using dbs from 1 to 8. I handle redis errors and all programs are working fine and reconnects to given db in most cases but when restarting redis server errors 110 (timed out) and 113 (no route) occur all programs reconnects to db0. Is there any way in which I can protect myself from that? as i said in case of error 111 (connection refused) all programs reconnect to given db and there is no problem. Example:

> r = redis.Redis('127.0.0.1', 6379, 3)

Comment: Without a self-contained reproducible test case, I doubt anyone can help you with this.